# Why can we say "half a [something]" but not "quarter a [something]"?

Tags: grammar

I often see the expression "half a [something]", but never "quarter a [something]".

Why is the first grammatically correct but not the second despite "half" and "quarter" both being fractions?

Comment: You can have *half a pound of flour* and with a slight twist in wording, *a quarter pound of flour*.

Comment: It's quite possible if used as a verb: *I'm going to quarter an apple.* I assume you're only talking about its use as a noun? (*I'm going to eat quarter an apple.*) Although it seems wrong to me, I'm not entirely convinced that it's *actually* asyntactic. The answer may simply be that *we just don't say it that way*. It's possible there's no rule or explanation for this other than simple non-use.

Answer (score 1):

"Half a cup" sounds like "Half of a cup"
So I imagine any word that ends in f and would normally require the word "of" for it to make sense, have "of" left out because it sounds like it's still there. (I can't think of any others examples so I'm still unsure).

"Quarter of a cup"

Comment: It's quite possible to say *add quarter a cup of milk*. So, although this is an interesting theory, I don't think it entirely works.

Comment: @JasonBassford I don't think I would say that. I'd say either 'add _a_ quarter cup of milk' or 'add a quarter _of_ a cup of milk'. However I would say 'I have a half hour appointment' and also 'I have a quarter hour appointment'

Comment: @BoldBen I've heard it both ways. *Add a quarter cup* is probably more common, but I find nothing wrong with *add quarter a cup*.

Comment: @JasonBassford I don't see anything wrong with it, it just doesn't seem natural. Perhaps it's a UK / US difference.